# Какую базу данных подключить, VS13, c#, winforms?

Tags: c#, база-данных, visual-studio, winforms

Курсач: нужно создать БД (это главное) Оптовой базы, ну и для интерфейса хочу использовать c# + winforms.
Что посоветуете использовать для создания БД? Чтоб было попроще с взаимодействием в с#
И какие проги использовать для создания БД, можете кинуть хотя бы статьи по этой теме.
Заранее спасибо!

Comment: localdb попробуй

Comment: А причём тут ваш UI-фреймворк к очень модельной базе данных?

Comment: @Konst Я раньше работал с локалдб, но мне бы что-то глобальное, чтоб было предусмотрено использование на разных компах

Comment: @VladD предложения приветствуются, что использовать в замен UI?

Comment: ms sql server express + SQL Server Management Studio

Comment: Вы уточните, как будет проходить защита курсача и на чем демонстрироваться. А то придете защищать, а у них там чистый комп без предустановок. Что тогда будете делать? В таких случаях надежнее всего старый добрый Access или SQLite, которые будут работать независимо.

Comment: @Vyacheslav: Что угодно. Выбор базы и выбор UI-фреймворка — совершенно друг от друга не зависимые вещи.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Я бы посоветовал попробовать [`Entity Framework`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/data/ef.aspx) совместно с [`Microsoft SQL Server Express`](https://www.microsoft.com/ru-ru/server-cloud/products/sql-server/overview.aspx).
В `Entity Framework` есть несколько подходов для создания базы данных, это:

1. Code First
2. Database First
3. Model First

Для удобства советую поставить [SQL Server Management Studio](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms174173.aspx) для того, чтобы работать с самой базой данных.

Очень удобно использовать `Code First`. Примеров масса, открываете ссылки и начинаете делать. [Приступая к работе с платформой Entity Framework (EF)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/data/ee712907)

Comment: Любопытно, посмотрю, спасибо